# Regex, sub out all alphabets

Tags: regex

I have a situation where I need only the numbers and the dash, like
2007-24.  I know how to use regular expressions to replace numbers, but
how would you regex all alphabets except the dash between the numbers.

Input:"CLOSED ORD NO 2007-24"

```
re.sub("[/-/^0-9/-]", '', self.text, flags=re.M)
```

Comment: The typical way to do data validation with a regular expression is to see if it matches a pattern and reject it if it doesn't, without trying to fix it. If your users put letters between the year and the month, they possibly didn't understand what they were trying to do and it's quite possible you won't fix anything by removing the letters.

Comment: @zneak - Moreover - if they are not understanding that is required you are then going on the assumption of guess what they meant - this might be very wrong and hence have invalid/detrimental data. Better to validate and if not correct ask them to try again (perhaps with additional help)

Comment: Well that was simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(\d+-\d+)|.', r'\1', self.text, flags=re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0fcWc/1)

**Regex details**

- `(\d+-\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits, `-`, 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `.` - any one char

The `\1` is a backreference to the Group 1 value (to keep it in the result).

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AGUMXt):

```
import re
s = "CLOSED ORD NO 2007-24"
print( re.sub(r"(\d+-\d+)|.", r'\1', s, flags=re.S) )
# => 2007-24
```